# How to append specific values to the existing dataframe from another dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to insert corresponding values into the main dataframe from subset dataframe, if not corresponding value doesnt match, it should get add in other column

```
import pandas as pd

# Sample main data
main_data = pd.DataFrame({
    'J-1': ['2001', '2002', '2003', '2004'],
    'X': [3225, 4602, 9412, None],
    'Y': [6875, 7557, 175, None],
    'Z': [0, 97, 0, None],
    'A': [163, 0, 3259, None],
    'Other': [468, 410, 500, None],
    'In': [10731, 12666, 13346, None],
    'Total': [18495.34643, 19086.79928, 20187.56618, None]
})

# Sample subset data
subset_data = pd.DataFrame({
    '1st': ['X'],
    'Winner': [9,751],
    'Winner %': ['75%'],
    '2nd': ['av'],
    '2nd P': ['Z'],
    '2nd Score': [2,760],
    '2nd %': ['21%'],
    'Margin': [6,991],
    'Margin%': ['54%'],
    '3rd': ['uv'],
    '3rd P': ['S'],
    '3rd Score': [304],
    '3rd %': ['2%'],
    'Others Score': [174],
    'Others %': ['1%'],
    'In': [12,989]
})
```

My desired output main_data should look like this, i want to achieve below result.

```
 J-1    X          Y    Z      A     Other  In       Total
 2001   3225    6875    0      163   468    10731    18495.34643
 2002   4602    7557    97     0     410    12666    19086.79928
 2003   9412    175     0      3259  500    13346    20187.56618
 2004   9751    0       2760   0     478    12989    25978
```

I tried this code,

```
for column_name in subset_data.columns:
    if column_name in main_data.columns:
        main_data.loc[zp_2017_index, column_name] = subset_data[column_name].iloc[0]
```

Can anyone help me to get desired result?

Comment: The logic is quite unclear. How would you do this with pen and paper?

Comment: I just want to fill my main_data blank row 2004, with corresponding value from subset_data which is for example X is present in first column, and its value is 9751, same i want to fill it in main_data Column X, and 9751 in 2004 row. @mozway

Comment: How you map the values is unclear

Comment: Mapping the value is based on column name from main_data and column values from subset_data, like in main_data my column name is X and in subset_data my X value which i want to fill lies in column value and its corresponding value lies in next column value which is 9751 in subset_data. @mozway

Comment: See below for a partial solution. You have to explicit how to identify "Other" unambiguously.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the year is the first column and that you want to map using either the column name or the name in the previous cell:

```
s = subset_data.loc[0]

mapper = (dict(zip(s, s.iloc[1:])) # map previous value
         |s.to_dict()              # map column name
         )

main_data.iloc[-1, 1:] = main_data.columns[1:].map(mapper)

# add total
main_data.iloc[-1, -1] = main_data.iloc[-1, 1:-1].sum()
```

Updated DataFrame:

```
    J-1       X       Y       Z       A  Other       In        Total
0  2001  3225.0  6875.0     0.0   163.0  468.0  10731.0  18495.34643
1  2002  4602.0  7557.0    97.0     0.0  410.0  12666.0  19086.79928
2  2003  9412.0   175.0     0.0  3259.0  500.0  13346.0  20187.56618
3  2004  9751.0     NaN  2760.0     NaN    NaN  12989.0  25500.00000
```

*You can further `fillna(0)` if needed. Also, note that "Other" is missing because there is no explicit column with this name. You have to first clean up the column names.*